# Using custom Darwin kernel

Tags: kernel, osx-mountain-lion, darwin, kernel-extension

I'm building a custom kernel for Mac OS (Mountain Lion, Darwin 2050.22.13).
I can build the kernel just fine and I can add stuff to it but I'm missing something.

To keep things short, here is a sample of what I'm trying to do.

Let's say that I want to add a function [my_func(void*)] to say, bsd/kern/kern_fork.c
I can add an include file and stick it into osfmk/bsd and change the Makefile so that the new .h file is now copied to BUILD/obj/RELEASE_X86_64/EXPORT_HDRS/

I also added the function name to config/BSDKernel.exports.
I can see the function with its symbol in /mach_kernel so it would appear to be fine.

Now, here's the tricky part. It's not tricky per se but I can't figure it out. What I want to do is to be able to make a call to my function from a kext that I am also writing. Basically it would be some sort of private API for me.

My kext compiles fine but when I run kextload/kextutil it complains that it can't find the my_func symbol.

(kernel) kxld[com.blah.foo.kext]: The following symbols are unresolved by this kext
(kernel) kxld[com.blah.foo.kext]:     _my_func

kextlibs returns:
For all architectures:
    com.apple.kpi.libkern = 12.3

for x86_64:
    1 symbol not found in any library kext

So the question is how do I do to make my function(s) visible to my kext(s)? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the symbols in `BSDKernel.exports` end up in the `com.apple.kpi.bsd` KPI, so you need to add that to your `OSBundleLibraries` dictionary in the kext's info.plist. I'm not 100% sure that's all you need to do, so let us know if that doesn't work.

**Update:**

The built-in KPIs are actually represented by pseudo-kexts within the "Plugins" directory of System.kext. So for the BSDKernel KPI, that's `/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext/` Perhaps that needs to be updated in kind?

`make all` doesn't seem to automatically build a new `System.kext`. There is a large section dedicated to System.kext in `config/Makefile`, however, and it seems to be part of the install targets. `make install` might do the trick. Or, if you're wary of that (as I am), this seems to be the crucial line:

```
    install $(INSTALL_FLAGS) $(OBJROOT)/BSDKernel.symbolset    $(DSTROOT)/$(INSTALL_KEXT_DIR)/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext/BSDKernel;         \
```

In other words, make a backup of your System.kext, then copy `BUILD/obj/RELEASE_X86_64/BSDKernel.symbolset` over `/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext/BSDKernel` and try booting.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks!
I thought the same initially but it doesn't seem to be problem. Here's part of my Info.plist in the kext that would make use of the function(s): 
<key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
       <dict>
  <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
  <string>10.8</string>
  <key>com.apple.kpi.bsd</key>
  <string>10.8</string>
  <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
  <string>10.8</string>
 </dict>
---

There must be something that I'm not doing. Funny enough, looking at the xxxx.exports files I can see the exported apis like current_task() and my own api isn't in any of those files.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another theory. Hope you can get it to work with that. By the way, 10.8 in OSBundleLibraries refers to the Darwin number - 10.8 means OSX 10.6.8, not Mountain Lion (that's 12.0). Just in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try hopefully sometimes today. I'll post an update as soon as I get this working. I'm documenting that stuff as I go.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to pmjordan I was able to get this to work. Took some effort but it seems to be good now.

The OSBundleLibraries now looks like this:

```
<key>OSBundleLibraries</key> 
    <dict> 
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key> 
        <string>12.3</string> 
        <key>com.apple.kpi.bsd</key> 
        <string>12.3</string> 
     </dict>
```

The GCC command looks like this:

```
cc -m64 -Xlinker -kext -static -c foo.c -o Contents/MacOS/foo -fno-builtin -nostdlib -lkmod -r -mlong-branch -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.Framework/Headers -Wall
```

In config/BSDKernel.exports:
_my_func

In osfmk/bsd, I have bdsfoo.h [which has an extern int my_func(void) ]

To build the kernel:

```
make ARCH_CONFIGS=X86_64 KERNEL_CONFIGS=RELEASE VERBOSE=YES
```

Once mach_kernel is copied to /

cp BUILD/obj/RELEASE_X86_64/BSDKernel.symbolset /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext/BSDKernel

**This was the missing link, thanks again to pmjordan**

reboot.
Build my kext and kextload, success!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted! Good to know in case I need to do this myself in future. :-)